# sed command with dynamic variable and spaces - not retaining spaces

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to insert a variable value into file from Jenkinsfile using shell script in the section
Variable value is dynamic. I am using sed.

Sed is working fine but it is not retaining the white spaces that the variable have at the beginning.

ex:
The value of >> repoName is "    somename"

```
stage('trying sed command') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh """
          #!/bin/bash -xel
          repo='${repoName}'
          echo "\$repo"
          `sed -i "5i \$repo" filename`
          cat ecr.tf
          """
        }
      }
    }
```

current output:

```
names [
   "xyz",
   "ABC",
somename
   "text"
 ]
```

Expected output:

```
names [
   "xyz",
   "ABC",
   somename
   "text"
 ]
```

How do i retain the spaces infront of the variable passing from sed

Comment: Why do you have the `sed` command in backticks? That will try to execute the output of the command as another command. Luckily it doesn't have any output because you're using `-i`.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool, awk would be simpler. But anyway, [edit] your question to show the command that works for you WITHOUT a variable so we know what syntax you're trying to get your variable to expand to.

Answer (score 0):

With

```bash
$ cat filename
names [
   "xyz",
   "ABC",
   "text"
 ]

$ repo=somename
```

we can do:

```bash
sed -E "3s/^([[:blank:]]*).*/&\\n\\1${repo},/" filename
```

```
names [
   "xyz",
   "ABC",
   somename,
   "text"
 ]
```

That uses capturing parentheses to grab the indentation from the previous line.

---

if `$repo` might contain a value with slashes, you can tell the shell to escape them with this (eye-opening) expansion

```bash
repo='some/name'
sed -E "3s/^([[:blank:]]*).*/&\\n\\1${repo//\//\\\/},/" filename
```

```
names [
   "xyz",
   "ABC",
   some/name,
   "text"
 ]
```

Comment: yes the repo variable contains slashes.

When trying the command you gave from my jenkins - its erroring out >> unexpected char: 0xFFFF @

Comment: I tried this >> sed -i "5i/^([[:blank:]]*).*/&\\n\$repo" filename

But output is also printing 
/^([[:blank:]]*).*/&

If we are able to get rid of these special chars then we are good

Comment: You need the `-E` option to recognize un-escaped capturing parentheses. Also, use the `s` command, not `i`

Answer (score 0):

I used 1 sed statement to add the content first to the file and then another sed statement for just adding spaces. This fixed my issue. All day i was trying to fit in one command did not work probably from Jenkins and shell usage. But using 2 sed commands as a workaround i was able to finish my task

Answer (score -1):

The `i` command skips over spaces after the `i` command to find the text to insert. You can put the text on a new line, with a backslash before the newline, to have the initial whitespace preserved.

```
stage('trying sed command') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh """
          #!/bin/bash -xel
          repo='${repoName}'
          echo "\$repo"
          `sed -i "5i \\\\\\
\$repo" filename`
          cat ecr.tf
          """
        }
      }
    }
```

I've tested this from a regular shell command line, I hope it will also work in the Jenkins recipe.

Comment: Nope still same from jenkins

Comment: Try doubling the backslashes so that Jenkins will keep the newline.

Comment: If i put \\\\ 4 slashes - there is no change
But If i put \\\\\\  6slashes i am get more spaces. Its a pain. not sure what else i can do

Comment: Nesting strings with escape characters is a pain.